# Unable to find date in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset in this form:

```
    company_name    date
0   global_infotech 2019-06-15
1   global_infotech 2020-03-22
2   global_infotech 2020-08-30
3   global_infotech 2018-06-19
4   global_infotech 2018-06-15
5   global_infotech 2018-02-15
6   global_infotech 2018-11-22
7   global_infotech 2019-01-15
8   global_infotech 2018-12-15
9   global_infotech 2019-06-15
10  global_infotech 2018-12-19
11  global_infotech 2019-12-31
12  global_infotech 2019-02-18
13  global_infotech 2018-06-16
14  global_infotech 2019-02-10
15  global_infotech 2019-03-15
16  Qualcom         2019-07-11
17  Qualcom         2018-01-11
18  Qualcom         2018-05-29
19  Qualcom         2018-10-06
20  Qualcom         2018-11-11
21  Qualcom         2019-08-17
22  Qualcom         2019-02-22
23  Qualcom         2019-10-16
24  Qualcom         2018-06-22
25  Qualcom         2018-06-14
26  Qualcom         2018-06-16
27  Syscin          2018-02-10
28  Syscin          2019-02-16
29  Syscin          2018-04-12
30  Syscin          2018-08-22
31  Syscin          2018-09-16
32  Syscin          2019-04-20
33  Syscin          2018-02-28
34  Syscin          2018-01-19
```

CONSIDERING TODAY'S DATE AS 1st JANUARY 2020, I WANT TO WRITE A CODE TO FIND THE NUMBER OF TIMES EACH COMPANY NAME IS OCCURING IN LAST 3 MONTHS. For example, suppose from 1st Oct 2019 to 1st Jan 2020, golbal_infotech's name is appearing 5 times, then 5 should appear infront of every global_infotech value like:

```
   company_name    date         appearance_count_last_3_months
0   global_infotech 2019-06-15       5
1   global_infotech 2020-03-22       5
2   global_infotech 2020-08-30       5
3   global_infotech 2018-06-19       5
4   global_infotech 2018-06-15       5
5   global_infotech 2018-02-15       5
6   global_infotech 2018-11-22       5
7   global_infotech 2019-01-15       5
8   global_infotech 2018-12-15       5
9   global_infotech 2019-06-15       5
10  global_infotech 2018-12-19       5
11  global_infotech 2019-12-31       5
12  global_infotech 2019-02-18       5
13  global_infotech 2018-06-16       5
14  global_infotech 2019-02-10       5
15  global_infotech 2019-03-15       5
```

Comment: Please show your work, how are you trying to achieve this, whats your problem exactly

Comment: I have tried to write a function, so that we can find the number of times each company name is repeating, in any particular duration. for example, suppose I need data for last 3 month, then simply I can pas 3 as agrument, and get the desire output. but that function is not at all working. In that function I have used groupyby and logical operators

Comment: Can you add the function to your post?

Comment: Is the output is of 'appearance_count_last_3_months' is 3 if the company_name is 'Syscin' and 'appearance_count_last_3_months' is 4 if company_name is 'Qualcom'?

Comment: Yes Anurag, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

you can create a custom function:

```
def getcount(company,month=3,df=df):
    df=df.copy()
    df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d',errors='coerce')
    df=df[df['company_name'].eq(company)]
    val=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq=str(month)+'m')).count().max().get(0)
    df['appearance_count_last_3_months']=val
    return df

getcount('global_infotech')
#OR
getcount('global_infotech',3)
```

**Update:**

since you have 92 different companies so you can use for loop:

```
lst=[]
for x in df['company_name'].unique():
    lst.append(getcount(x))
out=pd.concat(lst)
```

If you print `out` then you will get your desired output

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Here I have used only 3 companies but In original dataset, I have 92 different companies, so I can't use getcount function for every company one by one. So, is any way to automatic get that for all the companies.

Comment: @Rishavv updated answer...kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: @Rishavv also notice 1 thing that you will get `NaT` at index 20 in the given dataset bcz `2018-18-11` is not in gormat of `'%Y-%m-%d'......also if this answer solve your query try considering accepting this as an answer.....thnx ***:)***

Answer (score 1):

You can first filter the data for the last 3 months, and then groupby company name and merge back into the original dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'company_name': ['global_infotech', 'global_infotech', 'Qualcom','another_company'],
    'date': ['2019-02-18', '2021-07-02', '2021-07-01','2019-02-18']
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# filter for last 3 months
summary = df[df['date']>=datetime.now()-relativedelta(months=3)]

# groupby then aggregate with desired column name
summary = summary.rename(columns={'date':'appearance_count_last_3_months'})
summary = summary.groupby('company_name')
summary = summary.agg('count')

# merge summary back into original df, filling missing values with 0
df = df.merge(summary, left_on='company_name', right_index=True, how='left')
df['appearance_count_last_3_months'] = df['appearance_count_last_3_months'].fillna(0).astype('int')

# result:
df
      company_name       date  appearance_count_last_3_months
0  global_infotech 2019-02-18                               1
1  global_infotech 2021-07-02                               1
2          Qualcom 2021-07-01                               1
3  another_company 2019-02-18                               0
```